# SwiftUI Animation finish animation cycle

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I want to finish the loading animation nicely when changing the `refreshing` boolean in the following scenario:

```swift
public struct RefreshingView : View {
    @State private var rotation = Angle(degrees: 0.0)
    @Binding private var refreshing: Bool

    public init(refreshing: Binding<Bool>) {
        _refreshing = refreshing
    }

    public var body: some View {
        if refreshing {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .rotationEffect(rotation)
                .animateForever(using: .linear(duration: 1), autoreverses: false) {
                    rotation = Angle(degrees: -180)
                }
        } else {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .onAppear {
                    rotation = Angle(degrees: 0)
                }
        }
    }
}

public extension View {
  func animateForever(
      using animation: Animation = Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1),
      autoreverses: Bool = false,
      _ action: @escaping () -> Void
  ) -> some View {
      let repeated = animation.repeatForever(autoreverses: autoreverses)

      return onAppear {
          // That main.async is really important to change the animation from being explicit to implicit.
          // https://stackoverflow.com/a/64566746/1979703
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              withAnimation(repeated) {
                  action()
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Currently, the problem is that when I change the `refreshing` value the animation stops correctly, but it does not finsh the rotation so it looks like it is cut off. Is there a way to mitigate this by always finishing the current animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this working, there needs to be more of a disconnect between the `refreshing` flag and the animation:

- when the flag is turned on then the animation should begin
- after every 180 degrees rotation it should repeat if the flag is still on
- otherwise it should stop.

This means, instead of using an animation with `.repeatForever`, you need to perform a single animation and then launch it again when it completes if the flag is still on. In iOS 17 you can add a completion callback to `withAnimation`, which would be ideal for this purpose. Until then, you can achieve something similar using an `AnimatableModifier`, see [SwiftUI withAnimation completion callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57763709/20386264).

This shows it working:

```swift
// Credit to Centurion for the AnimatableModifier solution:
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/62855108/20386264
struct AnimationCompletionCallback: AnimatableModifier {

    var targetValue: Double
    var completion: () -> ()

    init(animatedValue: Double, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        self.targetValue = animatedValue
        self.completion = completion
        self.animatableData = animatedValue
    }

    var animatableData: Double {
        didSet {
            checkIfFinished()
        }
    }

    func checkIfFinished() -> () {
        if (animatableData == targetValue) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.completion()
            }
        }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
    }
}

public struct RefreshingView : View {

    let refreshing: Bool
    @State private var rotation = 0.0

    private func nextTurn() {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
            rotation += 180
        }
    }

    public var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotation))
            .onChange(of: refreshing) { newValue in
                if newValue {
                    nextTurn()
                }
            }
            .modifier(AnimationCompletionCallback(animatedValue: rotation) {
                if refreshing {
                    nextTurn()
                }
            })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var refreshing = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            Toggle("Refreshing", isOn: $refreshing).fixedSize()
            RefreshingView(refreshing: refreshing)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]