# SwiftUI: How to do a rotating refresh button animation

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I want a "refresh" button that behaves like this:

- As long as data is loading, it should rotate
- It should take at least one full rotation
- It should finish the current rotation when loading is done (not stop half way or spin back)

---

I have it somewhat working by calculating a delay, using a dedicated `@State` for the animation and using `Task.sleep(...)` before turning the animation off again. This seems to me like it's a terrible solution for multiple reasons:

- it's unreliable
- the animation spins back as the time calculation isn't exact
- it's trying to time the animation with imprecise date calculations
- ...

This is my current (terrible) solution:

```
struct LoadingView: View {
    @State var isLoadingData = false
    @State var isAnimating = false
    @State var lastRefreshStarted: Date?

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            handleRefresh()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath")
                .rotationEffect(isAnimating ? .degrees(180) : .degrees(0))
                .animation(
                    isAnimating ? Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false) :
                        .default, value: isAnimating)
        }
        .onChange(of: isLoadingData) {
            handleIsLoadingDataChange()
        }
    }
    
    func handleRefresh() {
        if isAnimating { return }
        Task {
            isLoadingData = true
            lastRefreshStarted = .now
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
            // loading for an unknown time here
            await MainActor.run {
                isLoadingData = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    func handleIsLoadingDataChange() {
        let newValue = isLoadingData
        if newValue {
            // start the animation as soon as data is loading
            withAnimation {
                isAnimating = newValue
            }
        } else {
            // if data is done loading, set a delay to fill up the next full second
            let elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(lastRefreshStarted ?? Date())
            let remainder = elapsedTime.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
            // add 0.1s buffer as calculation is not precise and it's better to spin back slightly
            // than spin back all the way to the previous rotation
            let delay = (1 - remainder) + 0.1
            Task {
                await Task.sleep(s: delay)
                await MainActor.run {
                    withAnimation {
                        isAnimating = isLoadingData
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: The answer to this post might help: [SwiftUI Animation finish animation cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76969841/20386264)

Comment: Which part is working and which part is not?

Comment: @ElTomato it's working, but it's unreliable and spinning back slightly every time

Comment: @BenzyNeez that's exactly what I've been looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Benzy Neez and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76969841/6385925), this fixes the issues I was having:

Instead of rotating forever and trying to stop at the right time, it is rotating by 180 degrees and extending it after the animation is complete but `isLoadingData` is still true.

```
struct LoadingView: View {
    @State var isLoadingData = false
    @State private var rotation = 0.0

    private func nextTurn() {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
            rotation += 180
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            handleRefresh()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath")
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotation))
                .onChange(of: isLoadingData) {
                    if isLoadingData {
                        nextTurn()
                    }
                }
                .modifier(AnimationCompletionCallback(animatedValue: rotation) {
                    if isLoadingData {
                        nextTurn()
                    }
                })
        }
    }

    func handleRefresh() {
        if isLoadingData { return }
        Task {
            isLoadingData = true
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
            // loading for an unknown time here
            await MainActor.run {
                isLoadingData = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct AnimationCompletionCallback: AnimatableModifier {
   var targetValue: Double
   var completion: () -> Void

   init(animatedValue: Double, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
       self.targetValue = animatedValue
       self.completion = completion
       self.animatableData = animatedValue
   }

   var animatableData: Double {
       didSet {
           checkIfFinished()
       }
   }

   func checkIfFinished() {
       if animatableData == targetValue {
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.completion()
           }
       }
   }

   func body(content: Content) -> some View {
       content
   }
}
```

Comment: Pleased to hear you found a solution. You are welcome to give the other answer an upvote if it helped ;)