How to acheive continuous animation when switching State in SwiftUI?
I have following UI:

Red Rectangle spin speed is base from slider's value. I'm acheiving this using .linear(duration:).repeatForever(autoreverses: false) (duration base on slider's value) and .id modifer to stop current animation whenever slider's value changed.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var level: Double = 0
    @State private var rotation: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            Rectangle().fill(.red)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .id(level)
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotation))
                .animation(level > 0 ? .linear(duration: 2 / level).repeatForever(autoreverses: false) : .linear(duration: 2), value: rotation)
            
            Spacer().frame(height: 12)
            Slider(value: $level, in: 0...3, step: 1)
            HStack {
                Text("0")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                Spacer()
                Text("1")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                Spacer()
                Text("2")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                Spacer()
                Text("3")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
            }
        }
        .padding(16)
        .onChange(of: level, perform: { _ in
            rotation += 360
        })
    }
}

My current issue is when user change slider's value, Rectangle is reset to initial state because of .id so it create a glitch.
Here is video link of how my code currently work: https://imgur.com/a/6bsUJzm
My question is how to get smooth transition between state when user change slider's value? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated!

One way to fix is to avoid using .repeatForever for the animation. Instead:

perform a quarter turn.
on completion, check if the level is > 0.
if it is, trigger another quarter turn.

Since iOS 17, an animation that is triggered using withAnimation can have a completion callback. So this would be one way of triggering the follow-on animation. However, doing it this way gives a rather stuttering animation.
An alternative technique is to use an Animatable ViewModifier to track the animation and perform an action when it completes. Doing it this way works more smoothly. The answer to SwiftUI Animation finish animation cycle provides a generic modifier that can be used for this purpose (it was my answer). That post was also concerned with a continuous rotation, so it is quite a similar issue.
Here is the updated example. Some more notes:

The .id modifier should be removed.

It is important that the animation modifier appears after the AnimationCompletionCallback.

Since .repeatForever is no longer used, the animation modifier can be simplified (a ternary operator is not needed).

It is simpler to apply the .fontWeight for the slider labels to the HStack, instead of to each individual label.

You were using a deprecated version of .onChange before. If in fact you are targeting a version of iOS earlier than iOS 17 then use the commented version provided in the code below.


var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 16) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.red)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotation))

            // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76969841/20386264
            .modifier(
                AnimationCompletionCallback(animatedValue: rotation) {
                    if level > 0 {
                        rotation += 90
                    }
                }
            )
            .animation(.linear(duration: 2 / max(1, level)), value: rotation)
        Spacer().frame(height: 12)
        Slider(value: $level, in: 0...3, step: 1)
        HStack {
            Text("0")
            Spacer()
            Text("1")
            Spacer()
            Text("2")
            Spacer()
            Text("3")
        }
        .fontWeight(.semibold)
    }
    .padding(16)
    // Pre iOS 17: .onChange(of: level) { [oldVal = level] newVal in
    .onChange(of: level) { oldVal, newVal in
        if oldVal == 0 {
            rotation += 90
        }
    }
}



Thanks for your answer. My app's min version iOS is 15.0 so my best choice is using AnimationCompletionCallback

@duckSern1108 Yes, the approach using an Animatable ViewModifier probably gives a smoother animation anyway. Unfortunately, it is still not completely smooth and you notice it stuttering a bit if you try to use a smaller step size (such as 10 degrees instead of 90).
