# SwiftUI - Different reversal animation

Tags: animation, swiftui

I want the animation to ease out when going up, but ease in when reversing, i.e. an asymmetric animation. How do I go about this? The goal is a continuous bounce.

My current code:

```
struct JumpingCircle: View {
    @State var animating = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .offset(y: animating ? -100 : 0)
                .animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: animating)
             
            Button("Toggle") {
                self.animating.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    JumpingCircle()
}
```

Current:

[image: Current. Slowed it down for illustration]

How I want it:

[image: How I want it]

Preferably I want to support iOS 15+.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an animation with `.repeatForever`, you could perform a single animation and then launch it again when it completes. This way, the animation type can be changed with every repeat.

In iOS 17, a `PhaseAnimator` can be used to chain the two animations together:

```swift
struct JumpingCircle: View {
    var body: some View {
        PhaseAnimator([false, true]) { flag in
            Circle()
                .offset(y: flag ? 0 : -100)
        } animation: { flag in
            flag ? .easeIn(duration: 1) : .easeOut(duration: 1)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .padding(.top, 100)
    }
}
```

Pre iOS 17, you can achieve something similar using an `AnimatableModifier`, see [SwiftUI withAnimation completion callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57763709/20386264).

```swift
// Credit to Centurion for the AnimatableModifier solution:
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/62855108/20386264
struct AnimationCompletionCallback: AnimatableModifier {

    var targetValue: CGFloat
    var completion: () -> ()

    init(animatedValue: CGFloat, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        self.targetValue = animatedValue
        self.completion = completion
        self.animatableData = animatedValue
    }

    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        didSet {
            checkIfFinished()
        }
    }

    func checkIfFinished() -> () {
        if (animatableData == targetValue) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.completion()
            }
        }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
    }
}

struct JumpingCircle: View {
    @State var animating = false
    @State private var offset = CGFloat.zero

    private func toggleAnimation() {
        withAnimation(offset < 0 ? .easeIn(duration: 1) : .easeOut(duration: 1)) {
            offset = offset < 0 ? .zero : -100
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .offset(y: offset)
                .onChange(of: animating) { newValue in
                    if newValue {
                        toggleAnimation()
                    }
                }
                .modifier(
                    AnimationCompletionCallback(animatedValue: offset) {
                        if animating {
                            toggleAnimation()
                        }
                    }
                )
            Button("Toggle") {
                animating.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Bouncing]

Comment: Awesome! Will check it out.

Comment: Answer updated to show how a `PhaseAnimator` could be used with iOS 17