# Dismissing a SwiftUI view using PhaseAnimator crashes the app

Tags: ios, swiftui, crash

I am trying to use `PhaseAnimator` that was introduced in iOS 17 to perform some pretty sweet looking animations. However, I noticed a problem that whenever the view using `PhaseAnimator` gets dismissed, and if the animation is running, the app crashes. I've managed to reproduce this in a small sample project:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresenting = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Present", action: {
            isPresenting = true
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresenting, content: {
            AnimatedView()
        })
    }
}

struct AnimatedView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello")
                .phaseAnimator([1, 1.3]) { content, phase in
                    content.scaleEffect(
                        CGSize(width: phase, height: phase),
                        anchor: .center
                    )
                }

            Button("Dismiss", action: {
                dismiss()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the example, there's nothing crazy in there, at least from what I can tell. Here's the stack trace of the crash:

```
Simultaneous accesses to 0x102b079c0, but modification requires exclusive access.
Previous access (a modification) started at SwiftUI`OUTLINED_FUNCTION_0 + 8352 (0x1c571eb30).
Current access (a read) started at:
0    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000192c95ec8 swift::runtime::AccessSet::insert(swift::runtime::Access*, void*, void*, swift::ExclusivityFlags) + 428
1    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000192c960dc swift_beginAccess + 72
2    SwiftUI                            0x00000001c571ca90 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_0 + 10144
3    SwiftUI                            0x00000001c583a898 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_21 + 11580
4    SwiftUI                            0x00000001c4cccec4 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_31 + 7832
5    SwiftUI                            0x00000001c4cccec4 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_31 + 7556
6    SwiftUI                            0x00000001c59814f8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_31 + 1452
7    SwiftUI                            0x00000001c57ab900 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_83 + 84188
8    SwiftUI                            0x00000001c57ab900 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_83 + 79588
9    SwiftUI                            0x00000001c57ab900 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_83 + 79548
10   SwiftUI                            0x00000001c57ab900 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_83 + 79680
11   AttributeGraph                     0x00000001b2c03748 __swift_instantiateConcreteTypeFromMangledName + 4000
12   AttributeGraph                     0x00000001b2bf2930 AG::Node::destroy(AG::Graph&) + 188
13   AttributeGraph                     0x00000001b2be87b0 AG::Subgraph::invalidate_now(AG::Graph&) + 1184
14   AttributeGraph                     0x00000001b2be8678 AG::Graph::invalidate_subgraphs() + 192
15   AttributeGraph                     0x00000001b2be13c8 AG::Graph::Context::~Context() + 348
16   AttributeGraph                     0x00000001b2bfa740 AGGraphInvalidate + 32
17   SwiftUI                            0x00000001c571ca90 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_0 + 8400
18   SwiftUI                            0x00000001c583a898 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_21 + 32348
19   SwiftUI                            0x00000001c583a898 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_21 + 32124
20   SwiftUI                            0x00000001c583a898 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_21 + 32392
21   libobjc.A.dylib                    0x0000000180083080 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 200
22   libobjc.A.dylib                    0x0000000180082f18 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 256
23   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001804a62b4 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
24   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001803f0ecc __CFRunLoopPerCalloutARPEnd + 44
25   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001803eb9b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1976
26   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001803eb368 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
27   GraphicsServices                   0x000000018e9fba44 GSEventRunModal + 160
28   UIKitCore                          0x00000001852eff80 -[UIApplication _run] + 868
29   UIKitCore                          0x00000001852f3ee0 UIApplicationMain + 124
30   SwiftUI                            0x00000001c51fbfbc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_70 + 500
31   SwiftUI                            0x00000001c51fbfbc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_70 + 148
32   SwiftUI                            0x00000001c4f02f48 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_2 + 92
33   SimultaneousAccessesCrash          0x0000000102632f18 static SimultaneousAccessesCrashApp.$main() + 40
34   SimultaneousAccessesCrash          0x0000000102632fe4 main + 12
```

I should note that I've tried supplying a `trigger` to the `PhaseAnimator`, to no avail.

I can also note that I've filed feedback about this to Apple using Feedback Assistant (FB13655444).

A workaround that I've applied is to simply not use `PhaseAnimator` for this. In my actual use-case I want to animate between three different states, and what I've done (instead of using `PhaseAnimator`) is added an `.onAppear { ... }`, and inside I have a series of calls to `withAnimation(...)`, and all but the first one are wrapped in `DispatchQueue.main.async(after: ...)`. It ain't pretty, but it works.

Any ideas for more robust workarounds are greatly appreciated.

Comment: For me, the code doesn't crash, but the app just freezes after the sheet is dismissed.

Comment: Interesting. Which version of Xcode are you using? Which simulator/device? I'm using Xcode 15.2 (15C500b), and I've tested it on both my iPhone running iOS 17.3.1, and an iOS simulator running iOS 17.2.

Comment: Xcode 15.0 and similar on iOS 17.0.

Comment: I second Sweeper's result.

Comment: In my recent project, I've used `PhaseAnimator` for both one-shot and continuous animations and discovered the same thing: when view disappears, the CPU usage temporarily spikes and that causes freezes and app terminations by the system for excessive resource use, especially on older devices. I ended up replacing `PhaseAnimator` with other ways to animate.

Comment: For complex animations, I've made my views `Animatable` following this great tutorial: https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part1/

Comment: Other ways to chain animations together would be to use `completion` as parameter to `withAnimation` (added in iOS 17), or one of the other solutions to be found under [SwiftUI withAnimation completion callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57763709/20386264). As an example, the solution by *Centurion* is being used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77196668/20386264).

Comment: So it does seem like PhaseAnimator is more or less broken then. Well that's a bummer. Thanks for all the great tips on complex animations. I'll have a look at all of them!