# SwiftUI animations go out of sync with each other

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

I'm trying to animate a few different properties on different views. The animations are all using the same `Animation` (with the same duration), and they are all driven by the same property. However, I find that they quite quickly go out of sync with each other, and I don't understand why. Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isAnimating = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
                .fill(Color.yellow)
                .offset(x: isAnimating ? -30 : 0)
                .rotationEffect(isAnimating ? .degrees(-10) : .zero)

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
                .fill(Color.green.opacity(0.5))
                .offset(x: isAnimating ? 30 : 0)
                .rotationEffect(isAnimating ? .degrees(10) : .zero)

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
                .fill(Color.red)
                .scaleEffect(isAnimating ? 1.1 : 1)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            let animation = Animation.bouncy(duration: 0.5)
                .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)

            withAnimation(animation) {
                isAnimating = true
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

The only workaround I've found is to use a different `Animation` than `Animation.bouncy`, e.g. `Animation.linear` or `Animation.easeInOut`. In that case, the animations all stay in sync. That leads me to believe that this is related to `Animation.bouncy` somehow (other springy animations exhibit the same problem, e.g. `Animation.spring`).

This problem occurs in SwiftUI previews, on device, and on the iOS simulator (all using the latest software as of writing: iOS 17.4, Xcode 15.3).

Video: https://imgur.com/a/btVESSG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround would be to go with

```
Animation.interpolatingSpring(duration: 0.5)
```

Since`.bouncy` is a customized spring animation, you can use [interpolatingSpring](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/animation/interpolatingspring) and achieve the desired result

Per the docs:

> An interpolating spring animation that uses a damped spring model to produce values in the range [0, 1] that are then used to interpolate within the [from, to] range of the animated property. Preserves velocity across overlapping animations by adding the effects of each animation.

Comment: Great suggestion for a workaround, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @vrutberg how did it go?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug to me. The animations involving rotation and offset seem to add a delay before they reverse. The delay is almost as long as the animation itself (and more noticeable if you give the animation a longer duration).

As a workaround, you could use a `PhaseAnimator`  to chain the forwards and backwards animations together, instead of using `.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        PhaseAnimator([false, true]) { isAnimating in
            ZStack {
                // content as before
            }
            .animation(.bouncy(duration: 0.5), value: flag)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Agreed, it does look like a bug. Great idea on using the PhaseAnimator for this. I had problems using that in the past (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78059704/dismissing-a-swiftui-view-using-phaseanimator-crashes-the-app?noredirect=1#comment137616060_78059704), but I should give it a shot for this use case.