# Instantaneously returning SwiftUI view to its original position without animation

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I want to return a SwiftUI view to its original position without the animation applied to it. Basically, I'm cycling things through it manually and don't want to have to render too many of these views at once, so I'm only rendering two at a time. Is there a way for the animation to occur, then make it ignore the animation when returning to offset zero?

```
import SwiftUI
import Photos

struct ImageView: View {
    var asset: BetterUIImage
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: PhotosModel
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(uiImage: asset.image)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 320, height: 420, alignment: .center)
                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25))
                .shadow(radius: 4)
        }
        .offset(x: offset.width, y: offset.height)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(offset.width / 40)))
        .gesture(
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged({ gesture in
                offset = gesture.translation
            })
            .onEnded({ _ in
                withAnimation {
                    swipeCard(width: offset.width)
                }
            })
        )
    }
    
    func swipeCard(width: CGFloat) {
        switch width {
        case -500...(-150):
//            delete
            offset = CGSize(width: -500, height: 0)
            viewModel.next()
            viewModel.appendToPhotosToDelete(asset.asset)
        case 150...(500):
//            save
            offset = CGSize(width: 500, height: 0)
            viewModel.next()
        default:
            offset = .zero
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ImageView(asset: BetterUIImage(image:  UIImage(systemName: "trash")!, asset: PHAsset()))
}
```

I tried moving the offset around within the swipeCard function and to different spots within the drag gesture, none work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the drag gesture you are performing `swipeCard` using `withAnimation`. If you want to reset the offset when the animation completes then you can do this using a completion callback (requires iOS 17). And if you don't want it animated, just omit `withAnimation` for the reset:

```swift
DragGesture()
    .onChanged { gesture in
        offset = gesture.translation
    }
    .onEnded { _ in
        withAnimation {
            swipeCard(width: offset.width)
        } completion: {
            offset = .zero
        }
    }
```

If you need to support earlier iOS versions then you could use one of the other solutions to be found under [SwiftUI withAnimation completion callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57763709/20386264). As an example, the solution by *Centurion* is being used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77196668/20386264).

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed! I moved the viewModel.next() call to the completion as well because it was a bit weird before.